# How to determine from which script/service access is denied for specific user in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

On my client server there is a lot of services and scripts running.
In MySQL error.log I get this NOTE:
`2022-04-14T19:32:31.962446Z 490136 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

and that lines repeat all the time.

So my question is, how can I determine from which services or the script  I get access denied to MySQL server?  (because I was looking for and can not find any wrong passwords in the services or the scripts for the root user)

Comment: *2022-04-14T19:32:31.962446Z **490136** [Note] ..* Move up and look for the connecting process for connection #490136.